# Can we solve this using stars and bars?

Tags: combinatorics

The number of ways of distributing 12 identical oranges among 4 children so that every child gets at least one and no child more than 4 is 31.

My try: First of all give each child 1 orange and we are left with 8 oranges.
Then

3 3 2 0

3 3 1 1

3 2 2 1

2 2 2 2

and permuting each, we get total 31. But can we solve this using stars and bars?

Comment: Your try looks good. I have not much hope for stars and bars here. The outcome $31$ is a prime hence rare as binomial coëfficiënt. It is a nice problem however, and I can be wrong off course.

Comment: Coefficient of $x^{12}$ in $(x+x^2+x^3+x^4)^4$

Comment: @SandeepThilakan, will you please explain why did you choose $(x+x^2+x^3+x^4)^4$ as answer?

Comment: The coefficient of $x^{12}$ in the expansion of the given polynomial counts the way that between 1 to 4 objects distributed to $4$ groups gives a total of $12$ objects.

Of course, calculating what that exponent of $x^{12}$ is, is basically done by your method; but these days you can easily have a math application churn out the result for you instead of doing it all by hand. (Mathlab, Maple, Wolfram... etc.)

$(x+x^2+x^3+x^4)^4 = x^{16}+4 x^{15}+10 x^{14}+20 x^{13}+\color{red}{31 x^{12}}+40 x^{11}+44 x^{10}+40 x^{9}+31 x^{8}+20 x^{7}+10 x^{6}+4 x^{5}+x^{4}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As SandeepThilakan said in the comments above, the coefficient of $x^{12}$ in the expansion of the polynomial $(x^1+x^2+x^3+x^4)^4$ counts the way that between 1 to 4 objects distributed to 4 groups gives a total of 12 objects.

Using the binomial expansion theorem:
$$(x+x^2+x^3+x^4)^4 \\ = ((x+x^2)+x^2(x+x^2))^4 \\ = x^4(1+x)^4(1+x^2)^4 \\ = x^4 \left(\sum\limits_{i=0}^4 {4\choose i}x^i \right)\left(\sum\limits_{j=0}^4 {4\choose j}x^{2j} \right) \\= x^4 \sum\limits_{i=0}^4 \sum\limits_{j=0}^4 {4 \choose i}{4 \choose j} x^{i+2j}$$

So the coefficients of $x^{12}$ must be $${4 \choose 0}{4 \choose 4}+{4 \choose 2}{4 \choose 3}+{4 \choose 4}{4 \choose 2} = 31$$

Comment: Could you elaborate on that given polynomial? And why the coefficient of $x^{12}$ gives the number of ways?

Comment: Examine $(x^1+x^2+x^3+x^4)(x^1+x^2+x^3+x^4)(x^1+x^2+x^3+x^4)(x^1+x^2+x^3+x^4)$.   In order to determine the coefficients of $x^{12}$ in the expansion you just count the distinct ways to select terms in each four factors such that their exponents add up to $12$.  It's an analogous procedure.

Comment: Could you also give an interpretation of the binomial coefficient products $\binom{4}{0}\binom{4}{4} + \binom{4}{2}\binom{4}{3}+\binom{4}{4}\binom{4}{2}$.

Comment: @MusséRedi, we have to have $x^{i+2j}=x^8$ and Greham has done the same.

Comment: @GrahamKemp, so, I think Stars and Bars problems are particular examples of this method, right?

Comment: And what about a physical interpretation of the binomial coefficient products$\binom{4}{0}\binom{4}{4}+\binom{4}{2}\binom{4}{3}+\binom{4}{4} \binom{4}{2}$?

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution by generating functions, ellipses cover terms that don't influence the result:
\begin{align}
[z^{12}] (z + z^2 + z^3 + z^4)^4
  &= [z^{12}] \left( \frac{z (1 - z^4)}{1 - z} \right)^4 \\
  &= [z^8] (1 - z^4)^4 (1 - z)^{-4} \\
  &= [z^8] (1 - 4 z^4 + 6 z^8 - \cdots)
              \sum_{n \ge 0} \binom{-4}{n} (-1)^n z^n \\
  &= [z^8] (1 - 4 z^4 + 6 z^8 - \cdots) 
              \sum_{n \ge 0} \binom{n + 4 - 1}{4 - 1} z^n \\
  &= \binom{11}{3} - 4 \binom{7}{3} + 6 \binom{3}{3} \\
  &= 31
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Since you specifically refer to stars and bars, yes, it can be applied by first preassigning 1 orange to each child, and then applying inclusion-exclusion to exclude cases where one or more child gets 4 or more oranges.

With only the pre-assignment, the answer would be ${8+4-1 \choose 4-1}$ = ${11\choose 3}$

Applying inclusion to take care of the restrictions,

${11\choose 3} - {4\choose1}*{7\choose 3} + {4\choose2}*{3\choose3}$ = 31