# Combination with Repetition: 100 bikes, 4 warehouses question

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations

A bike collector has 100 indistinguishable bikes.
How many ways can the bikes be stored in four warehouses if warehouse 1 gets at least 10 bikes and warehouse 2 gets at least 10 but at most 20 bikes ?

Comment: Do you know how to solve a "stars a bars" problem? Can you see how to model this as a variant of that?

Comment: could you explain the solution briefly.

Comment: **Hint**: First put 10 bikes in warehouse 1 and 2. Then consider a way to count the number of possibilites to store your bikes in general minus the number of ways to sore your bikes, s.t. more than 20 are in warehouse 2. You might look around, this kind of question was answered several times before!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can we solve this using stars and bars?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/739198/can-we-solve-this-using-stars-and-bars)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a variant on the solution of Benson Lin, and basically as suggested in comments by Doug M and csts, start with only the constraint of at least 10 bicycles in warehouse 1 and 2. This gives you
$$
\binom{100-10-10+3}{3} = \binom{83}{3}
$$
possibilities. Now count the possibilities when warehouse 1 gets at least 10, and warehouse 2 gets at least 21. The number is
$$
\binom{100-10-21+3}{3} = \binom{72}{3}.
$$
Subtract the first from the second to get
$$
91\,881 - 59\,640 = 32\,241.
$$

Answer (score 0):

First, remove 20 bikes at the beginning. This is for the "at least" restraints in the question. Now consider for each possible value of the number of bikes in warehouse 2, which are $10,11,\cdots,20$.

For each case, we remove another $0$ to $10$ bikes.

Now we simply have to divide the remaining bikes among the warehouse 1, 3 and 4. This can be found with the aid of [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) which gives us the formula for $n$ bikes and $3$ warehouses as:

$$
\binom{n+3-1}{3-1} = \binom{n+2}{2} = \frac{(n+2)(n+1)}{2}
$$

Now we just have to sum with $n = 80,79,\cdots,70$. This gives us an answer of $32241$